# Python: Try and Except usage to determine if a file path exists

Tags: python, file, recursion, try-catch

I have a script that recursively searches source code for modules within that code to be able to source all required files.

I am working with a file structure that is somewhat predictable, so I can make a "best guess" to get the right path to this new module. There are some exceptions to this file path so it may not always lead to the right result.

I am attempting to use try catch to confirm that, for every module within a source file, there is actually a file at the path. If there isn't a file at the path, it makes another attempt of the path. If the module still doesn't exist, it will just remove the bad path from the modules array and skip it.

I want to print all of the correct paths to the files once the recursion is done and flag if there are file paths that aren't found.

My Python code is as follows:

```
modules = ["../pathsource1.c", "../path/source2.c"]

for module in modules: 
   try:
      with open(module, 'r') as f: 
          for line in f: 
              # search each line for keyword to see if there is a file
              if(module_name):
                 modules.append(path_to_module + module_name) 
   except: 
       print("path did not lead to a module.") 
       try:
           with open(new_module_path, 'r') as f:
               print("module found!")
               modules.append(new_module_path)
       except:
           print("module not found at any location")
       modules.remove(module) # remove old path, which was broken

print(modules) # should return only paths that exist  

expected output:

["../path/source1.c", "../path/source2.c", "../path/module1_in_source1.c", "path/module2_in_source1.c", "../path/module1_in_module2_in_source1.c", ...]
```

It works decently but it is not perfect. Sometimes the code is not raising an exception and then an incorrect path stays in the modules array. How do I improve this code?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is an "modifying a list while iterating on it" issue, with the exception handling and the file stuff as a red herring.

Comment: how are these two defined? path_to_module + module_name

Comment: @OCa Simplifying a bit, but I have a "library" of a sort that contains a ton of reusable source code with a file structure that is predictable (i.e. .../library/modules/module_name/module_name_version). These source modules may also have module dependencies, so the script scans every line in that file to collect any other source modules. So it's a combination of some Regex to find any instantiated modules and also knowing that the modules all follow a similar path structure ".../library/modules/module_name/module_name_version," and then searching those paths for more.

Comment: @Blckknght I don't disagree.

Comment: I checked: list.append indeed allows to recursively increase the iterator along with the loop. Just beware circular imports. A set instead of most would prevent duplicates.

Comment: A predictable structure all right, however this remains something we cannot reproduce ([mre]). Définitive answers may be difficult to produce.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to add a bit more explanation. Why are you waiting for an exception? I assume you expect a `FileNotFoundError` exception. It is a good practice to only catch the exception you want to handle. Otherwise, another exception could occur which isn't related to the FileNotFound.

You probably could use the os module `os.path.exists()` to check if a path exists.

Another problem causing your error could be that you are modifying your list at the same time you are looping through it. So when you remove an element from the list the indexes update so now your current element is now the next element. So in the next iteration of the `for` loop after an element removal, you will actually skip one because the list was updated. I suggest you to create a new list with the valid paths instead of removing from the one you are looping over.

Comment: Thanks. Removing the "bad paths" after the loop did solve the problem somewhat however it seems like there are indexes that are being skipped over still.

Comment: I suggested, to create a list with the `ok_paths`, not removing the paths from the list, it would be like a filter, you only copy the list elements of the paths that do exists and ignore the ones that don't. At the end of the loop you `ok_paths` list should contain only paths that exist.